# Labels inside input fields - cant click on text when in FORM, but can within LABEL

Tags: jquery, forms, label

http://jsfiddle.net/ndreckshage/sPHBd/

Can anyone help with this code? I'm trying to use a plugin from this site http://attardi.org/labels2/#info

If you notice in the jsfiddle, if you click on the text (email/password) it doesnt activate the text field, but if you click on the text area (not text itself, it works fine)

And in the lowest example, it works correctly

Thanks for any help

Comment: The hell are you trying to do with this code? Why would you need JavaScript or better yet jQuery for this?

Comment: There're a lot better jQuery plugins for `placeholder`, yes that's its name. google it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. Check it out :  http://jsfiddle.net/sPHBd/1/

Comment: The problem was, you were assigning the class `input` to the element `<td>`, it must be a `<label>`